# Setting up RStudio Portable Default R version

Tags: r, rstudio, portability

I recently discovered a portable version of R and RStudio @

http://rportable.sourceforge.net/

*Open source rocks!*

At any-rate, I am jumping from pc to pc at my university, and I'd like to get Portable R-studio to recognize Portable R as the default R version. Most computers at the university already have several versions of r-installed, and RStudio uses one of those versions of R. When I go into the Global Options to change the default version, it does not "see" portable R on the USB drive.

I am basically hopping I can run R without constantly having to download packages, specifying the work directory, downloading Scripts, data from Google Drive, etc...

Any suggestions? I am open. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: @jonathan Mostly windows 7, 64 and 32 bit machines using 32 bit R.

Comment: @k6adams - The accepted answer points to touching the registry, and it is not needed. You might want to reconsider the situation, for the benefit of readers.

Comment: The last available version of RStudio Portable is 0.97, and it has no debugging AFAIK. The installable version 0.99 has it (a huge difference!).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**I did not need to touch the registry**.

I first installed R portable and then R Studio portable, both from Sourceforge.
After launching R Studio for the first time, I was shown the option of choosing the installation of R to be used, as shown in

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R

I browsed to branch \PortableApps\R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin, where executables are located. There I selected the 64-bit version.

If you want to change later the version used, you open R Studio and go to Tools -> Option -> General -> R Version.

This avoids modifying the registry, with the two advantages of Portable Apps:

1. Leaving no trace of the app in the system (or, at least, a much milder one).
2. Being really portable (or, at least, much more so).

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, RStudio uses the system registry to find where installed versions of R are located. You'll need to edit the registry yourself to let it know about new versions. Fortunately you can do this in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` so admin rights shouldn't be required. Here are the keys and values you'll want to write:

http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Does-R-use-the-Registry_003f

More detail about how RStudio selects the R version to run here:

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R

Comment: @k6adams - Touching the registry apparently works, but it is not needed. Se the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

The link to [R Portable](http://rportable.sourceforge.net/) above is a bit misleading. In order to run a portable version of R **AND** RStudio, you also need the 27MB portable RStudio [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rportable/files/R-Studio/0.97.551/). What's even more confusing is that it has the same name as the RPortable file.

It took me a bit of time to figure that one out. Perhaps you could edit your question to point to both for those who wish for an IDE?

And, IMHO, it's not **truly** portable, because when you move from one machine to another you need to specify the R version on your USB drive and also the work directory. Pity.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to link RStudio (not portable version) to the aforementioned version of R Portable, directly through Global Options -> R Version -> Choose a specific version of R -> Browse,
and the trick was selecting the R-Portable\App\R-Portable folder. Choosing another one doesnt allow RStudio to find the instalation.

Im running RStudio 1.1.463.

Bye!