# No RTools compatible with R version 3.5.0 was found

Tags: r, data.table, package, devtools, rtools

I had problems installing data.table for R version 3.5.0, and was advised to check that RTools was properly installed.

After installing RTools 3.5 (this seems to be the latest) I typed

```
find_rtools(T)
```

I got the following message:

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but no version 
of Rtools compatible with R 3.5.0 was found. 
(Only the following incompatible version(s) of Rtools were found:3.4,3.5)

Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools from 
http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/.
```

So on the one hand it looks like I do have 3.5 installed, but it seems to think there is a newer/different version.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The second link in particular is very useful! My guess is that your most recent `RTools` is not in your `PATH`. Or it is in your `PATH` but another (incompatible) `Rtools` version takes precedence.

Comment: @Tung you should make this an answer - it was really helpful!

Comment: @kath: add an answer as you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem was `Rtools 3.5` was not in your Windows system `PATH` thus `find_rtools` couldn't find it. Another possibility was that an incompatible version of `Rtools` was in the `PATH`

**Best practice for installing `Rtools`:**

- Download the [latest version](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)
- Install `RTools` at default recommended location (at the root of your `C` drive): `C:/Rtools/`
- <**Important**> Check the box that allows `Rtools` to modify system PATH

[image]
[image]

After the installation, we can double check by running this command inside `R`

```
R> Sys.getenv('PATH')
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.5.0\\bin\\x64;c:\\Rtools\\bin;c:\\Rtools\\mingw_64\\bin;
```

See also this [guide](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Install-Rtools-for-Windows)

---

**Edit**: for those who don't have Administration rights, see these links:

- [Rtools with R portable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34368287/786542)
- [Building R packages on Windows without administrator access](https://gist.github.com/ofurkusi/09a432ed1fb15c72eec9)
- [Setting up RStudio Portable Default R version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26261262/786542)

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

The utility `find_rtools` has been moved to the package [`pkgbuild`](https://github.com/r-lib/pkgbuild) (as noted in `devtools` [News](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/blob/ab568e954252a95f2279281784480afd117e63fa/NEWS.md)). The function `pkgbuild::find_rtools()` correctly discovers `Rtools` 3.5 in my system.

**Old answer**

I had this same problem and it occurs because `devtools` has not been updated to consider the newest version of RTools (3.5). Here is an easy fix that should work while they update the package:

```
# add missing RTools 3.5 info
v_i = devtools:::version_info
v_i[["3.5"]] = v_i[["3.4"]]
v_i[["3.5"]]$version_max = "3.5.99"
assignInNamespace(x     = "version_info",
                  value = v_i,
                  ns    = "devtools")

# now find_rtools should work properly
devtools::find_rtools()
```

Of course, this approach assumes that `devtools::find_rtools` worked for you before updating R and RTools. If this is not the case, then you might have a faulty installation and/or PATH variable as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite sure RTools 3.5 works with R-3.5 . I haven't used find_rtools() before, but I did manage to compile data.table from source a week ago. Here's how I did it:

After installing R 3.5 and RTools 3.5, I manually checked/modified the following system-envs (somehow the RTools installer failed to do this automatically, so I went through the readme from RTools and do it manually):
 BINREF = "C:/Rtools/mingw_$(WIN)/bin/"   (with "s, slashes are /)
 PATH = ";C:\Rtools\bin"     ("s are optional , slashes are \ )

Then I downloaded the source package for data.table(was version 1.10.4-3) and ran R CMD INSTALL data.table_1.10.4-3.tar.gz from windows command-line. With a working RTools, the package would successfully compile.
I also tried the install.packages(data.table) from R-GUI, where I got pop-up window to confirm compilation from source.

Anyway, I believe cran now provides a working windows-binary for data.table, so using RTools is no longer necessary.