# Rtools 3.5 not recognized?

Tags: r, rstudio

I just installed R3.5 (and RStudio) on a new computer that has not previously had R on it.  I then installed the devtools package, and when I went to install a package off of github, I realized (when prompted!) I had forgotten to install Rtools, so I followed the prompts to do so. Interestingly, this R tools installed to the directory of C:\RBuildTools by default and with no prompts for setting path variables as I had recalled in previous versions.

When I reloaded R, I was prompted to install Rtools again. My path contained no reference to Rtools (or the Rbuildtools directory), and remembering that my past installations had used the dir C:\Rtools, I decided to uninstall C:\RBuildTools and installed a fresh version off http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ ( installed version 3.5) into C:\Rtools.  In installation I had the path variable option checked.

I reloaded RStudio and checked to make sure Rtools was found:

```
> devtools::find_rtools()
Error in system(full, intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = quiet, ...) : running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.0/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD config CC' had status 2
```

However, rtools appears in my PATH:

```
> Sys.getenv("PATH")
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.5.0\\bin\\x64;C:\\Rtools\\bin;..."
```

So this doesn't appear to be an issue with Rtools not being added properly to my Path variable.  Google searches have turned up seemingly related errors but nothing so far that solves my issue. I have tried both suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50034966/no-rtools-compatible-with-r-version-3-5-0-was-found) and neither have worked.  I wonder if this could be related to RStudio.

Comment: https://github.com/catavallejos/BASiCS/issues/9

Comment: Unfortunately, Rtools is already in my path.  I've clarified my post to more explicitly state that Rtools is in my path variable and it is pointing to the correct directory.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer?

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50134225/5443023) in a related question

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem with RTools 3.5.
The installer did add `C:\RTools\bin` to the PATH, but it did not add
`C:\RTools\mingw_64\bin` which apparently did cause some confusion.

After adding `C:\RTools\mingw_64\bin` to the PATH, everything was fine.

My symptoms were a bit different though: RStudio reported an error when trying to "Install and Restart" my package that RTools were not found, while `devtools::find_rtools()` reported them to be present.

Comment: This worked for me too - although I have first *replaced* the path - which did not work! Only **adding** it, as you have said, actually does the job. Just wanted to point this out if someone else should run astray as I did

Comment: How does one exactly "add" the path?

Answer (score 2):

I have a comprehensive answer here for `rtools` not being recognized thru use of `pkgbuild`

[`devtools::install_github(repo)` keeps installing rtools35.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52081886/devtoolsinstall-githubrepo-keeps-installing-rtools35-exe/52083648#52083648)

The code snippet acknowledges the github comment this is posted (helped by r-sig-finance citizens)

However, (I can't comment) the error of `find_tools()` has disappeared but remains in `devtools::install_bitbucket()` for the new code that was the ultimate target and is in a src/master on BB cloud.

I unloaded the devtools and installed with remotes

```
unloadNamespace("devtools")
library(remotes)
install_bitbucket(author/repo)
```

As I said the problem with `find_tools` is taken care of by `pkgbuild` loading all items

Answer (score 0):

Try updating RStudio to the latest version.

I had this problem after updating Rtools to 3.5 and found that updating RStudio to 1.1.447 fixed it.

If that doesn't work, Can you run `rstudioapi::versionInfo()$version` from inside RStudio and share the output?

If this isn't your problem I found that RStudio keeps a log - and it helped me isolate this issue. In my case the file was located in, "C:\Users\my_windows_username\AppData\Local\RStudio-Desktop\log\rsession-my_windows_username.log"

I found this warning in the log time that corresponed to the error in RStudio

> WARNING Unknown Rtools version: 3.5; LOGGED FROM: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::r_util::scanRegistryForRTools(HKEY, bool, std::vector*) C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\core\r_util\RToolsInfo.cpp:269

This indicated that RStudio didn't recognize 3.5, which led me to check for an updated version of RStudio.

Comment: There was this change to RStudio to add 3.5 support https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/commit/610faead630a7d184bd243baba466f8662c5b478#diff-8face90843f875e11f9cac5641ed61fc