# error installing devtools in R 3.5.2 (probably related to rcmdcheck)

Tags: r, github, devtools

I'm not able to install packages from github using the install_github function in devtools. I have read many other questions on the topic but didn't find a solution. Here is my case:

I have just installed R 3.5.2 and R Studio 1.1.463. I have Rtools 3.5.0.4.
When I open Rstudio and try to install devtools with install.packages("devtools") I get the following log:

```
> install.packages("devtools")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/davidri/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘ps’, ‘magrittr’, ‘backports’, ‘Rcpp’, ‘ini’, ‘processx’, ‘R6’, ‘assertthat’, ‘crayon’, ‘curl’, ‘mime’, ‘openssl’, ‘desc’, ‘prettyunits’, ‘rprojroot’, ‘rlang’, ‘xopen’, ‘clipr’, ‘clisymbols’, ‘fs’, ‘gh’, ‘glue’, ‘whisker’, ‘callr’, ‘cli’, ‘digest’, ‘git2r’, ‘httr’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘memoise’, ‘pkgbuild’, ‘pkgload’, ‘rcmdcheck’, ‘remotes’, ‘rstudioapi’, ‘sessioninfo’, ‘usethis’, ‘withr’


  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
          binary source needs_compilation
rcmdcheck  1.3.1  1.3.2             FALSE

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/ps_1.3.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 305676 bytes (298 KB)
downloaded 298 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/magrittr_1.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 155587 bytes (151 KB)
downloaded 151 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/backports_1.1.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 65997 bytes (64 KB)
downloaded 64 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/Rcpp_1.0.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 4479299 bytes (4.3 MB)
downloaded 4.3 MB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/ini_0.3.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 15467 bytes (15 KB)
downloaded 15 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/processx_3.2.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 306262 bytes (299 KB)
downloaded 299 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/R6_2.3.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 57273 bytes (55 KB)
downloaded 55 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/assertthat_0.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 53713 bytes (52 KB)
downloaded 52 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/crayon_1.3.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 749419 bytes (731 KB)
downloaded 731 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/curl_3.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2986344 bytes (2.8 MB)
downloaded 2.8 MB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/mime_0.6.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 47811 bytes (46 KB)
downloaded 46 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/openssl_1.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3937329 bytes (3.8 MB)
downloaded 3.8 MB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/desc_1.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 283292 bytes (276 KB)
downloaded 276 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/prettyunits_1.0.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 33096 bytes (32 KB)
downloaded 32 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/rprojroot_1.3-2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 84007 bytes (82 KB)
downloaded 82 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/rlang_0.3.0.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1031444 bytes (1007 KB)
downloaded 1007 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/xopen_1.0.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 24454 bytes (23 KB)
downloaded 23 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/clipr_0.4.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 37368 bytes (36 KB)
downloaded 36 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/clisymbols_1.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 20882 bytes (20 KB)
downloaded 20 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/fs_1.2.6.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 954023 bytes (931 KB)
downloaded 931 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/gh_1.0.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 49081 bytes (47 KB)
downloaded 47 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/glue_1.3.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 108422 bytes (105 KB)
downloaded 105 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/whisker_0.3-2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 80986 bytes (79 KB)
downloaded 79 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/callr_3.1.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 245254 bytes (239 KB)
downloaded 239 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/cli_1.0.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 589903 bytes (576 KB)
downloaded 576 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/digest_0.6.18.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 194555 bytes (189 KB)
downloaded 189 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/git2r_0.23.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2874053 bytes (2.7 MB)
downloaded 2.7 MB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/httr_1.4.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 496847 bytes (485 KB)
downloaded 485 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/jsonlite_1.6.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1160524 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/memoise_1.1.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 36540 bytes (35 KB)
downloaded 35 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/pkgbuild_1.0.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 128427 bytes (125 KB)
downloaded 125 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/pkgload_1.0.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 154873 bytes (151 KB)
downloaded 151 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/remotes_2.0.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 272964 bytes (266 KB)
downloaded 266 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/rstudioapi_0.8.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 178918 bytes (174 KB)
downloaded 174 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/sessioninfo_1.1.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 46417 bytes (45 KB)
downloaded 45 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/usethis_1.4.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 520837 bytes (508 KB)
downloaded 508 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/withr_2.1.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 151064 bytes (147 KB)
downloaded 147 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/devtools_2.0.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 383825 bytes (374 KB)
downloaded 374 KB

package ‘ps’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘magrittr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘backports’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘ini’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘processx’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘R6’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘assertthat’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘crayon’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘mime’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘openssl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘desc’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘prettyunits’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘rprojroot’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘xopen’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘clipr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘clisymbols’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘fs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘gh’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘glue’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘whisker’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘callr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘cli’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘digest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘git2r’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘httr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘jsonlite’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘memoise’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘pkgbuild’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘pkgload’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘remotes’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘rstudioapi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘sessioninfo’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘usethis’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘withr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘devtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\davidri\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGoihSi\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘rcmdcheck’

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/src/contrib/rcmdcheck_1.3.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1408582 bytes (1.3 MB)
downloaded 1.3 MB

In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rcmdcheck’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\davidri\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGoihSi\downloaded_packages’
```

**QUESTION: can I assume devtools is properly installed based on this log?**

Then I try to use devtools to install packages from github, but it doesn't work. That's why I think devtools is not properly installed. Example:

```
devtools::install_github("vinayudyawer/ATT")
Downloading GitHub repo vinayudyawer/ATT@master
Installing 36 packages: ade4, adehabitatHR, adehabitatLT, adehabitatMA, BH, bindr, bindrcpp, CircStats, colorspace, deldir, dplyr, fansi, filehash, ggplot2, gtable, labeling, lazyeval, lubridate, maptools, munsell, pillar, pkgconfig, plogr, plyr, purrr, raster, RColorBrewer, reshape2, scales, sp, stringi, stringr, tibble, tidyselect, utf8, viridisLite
Installing packages into ‘C:/Users/davidri/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/ade4_1.7-13.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 5204011 bytes (5.0 MB)
downloaded 5.0 MB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/adehabitatHR_0.4.15.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1387759 bytes (1.3 MB)
downloaded 1.3 MB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/adehabitatLT_0.3.23.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2344449 bytes (2.2 MB)
downloaded 2.2 MB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/adehabitatMA_0.3.12.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 843921 bytes (824 KB)
downloaded 824 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/BH_1.66.0-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 17880019 bytes (17.1 MB)
downloaded 17.1 MB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/bindr_0.1.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 17686 bytes (17 KB)
downloaded 17 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/bindrcpp_0.2.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 623724 bytes (609 KB)
downloaded 609 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/CircStats_0.2-6.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 172817 bytes (168 KB)
downloaded 168 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/colorspace_1.3-2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 527859 bytes (515 KB)
downloaded 515 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/deldir_0.1-15.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 237915 bytes (232 KB)
downloaded 232 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/dplyr_0.7.8.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3069483 bytes (2.9 MB)
downloaded 2.9 MB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/fansi_0.4.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 220201 bytes (215 KB)
downloaded 215 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/filehash_2.4-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 310000 bytes (302 KB)
downloaded 302 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/ggplot2_3.1.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3621915 bytes (3.5 MB)
downloaded 3.5 MB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/gtable_0.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 85156 bytes (83 KB)
downloaded 83 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/labeling_0.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 61841 bytes (60 KB)
downloaded 60 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/lazyeval_0.2.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 166601 bytes (162 KB)
downloaded 162 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/lubridate_1.7.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1569004 bytes (1.5 MB)
downloaded 1.5 MB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/maptools_0.9-4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2143336 bytes (2.0 MB)
downloaded 2.0 MB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/munsell_0.5.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 243588 bytes (237 KB)
downloaded 237 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/pillar_1.3.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 154980 bytes (151 KB)
downloaded 151 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/pkgconfig_2.0.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 22208 bytes (21 KB)
downloaded 21 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/plogr_0.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 18735 bytes (18 KB)
downloaded 18 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/plyr_1.8.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1297496 bytes (1.2 MB)
downloaded 1.2 MB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/purrr_0.2.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 295158 bytes (288 KB)
downloaded 288 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/raster_2.8-4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3768262 bytes (3.6 MB)
downloaded 3.6 MB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/RColorBrewer_1.1-2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 55444 bytes (54 KB)
downloaded 54 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/reshape2_1.4.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 625902 bytes (611 KB)
downloaded 611 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/scales_1.0.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1064924 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/sp_1.3-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1869135 bytes (1.8 MB)
downloaded 1.8 MB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/stringi_1.2.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 15268347 bytes (14.6 MB)
downloaded 14.6 MB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/stringr_1.3.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 194509 bytes (189 KB)
downloaded 189 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/tibble_1.4.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 243931 bytes (238 KB)
downloaded 238 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/tidyselect_0.2.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 624866 bytes (610 KB)
downloaded 610 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/utf8_1.1.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 214701 bytes (209 KB)
downloaded 209 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/viridisLite_0.3.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 60491 bytes (59 KB)
downloaded 59 KB

package ‘ade4’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘adehabitatHR’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘adehabitatLT’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘adehabitatMA’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘BH’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘bindr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘bindrcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘CircStats’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘colorspace’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘deldir’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘fansi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘filehash’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘gtable’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘labeling’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘lazyeval’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘lubridate’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘maptools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘munsell’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘pillar’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘pkgconfig’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘plogr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘plyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘purrr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘raster’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘RColorBrewer’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘reshape2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘scales’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘sp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘stringi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘stringr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘tibble’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘tidyselect’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘utf8’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘viridisLite’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\davidri\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGoihSi\downloaded_packages
Error in processx::run(bin, args = real_cmdargs, stdout_line_callback = real_callback(stdout),  : 
  System command error
```

Same when trying to install other packages from github such as...

```
> devtools:install_github("twitter/AnomalyDetection")
```

**QUESTION: Is the problem related to the installation of devtools as I think? Any suggestion on how to solve it?**

In case it helps:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/davidri/Documents/R/win-library/3.5" "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.2/library"  

> Sys.info()
                     sysname                      release                      version                     nodename                      machine 
                   "Windows"                      "7 x64" "build 7601, Service Pack 1"                    "DAVIDPC"                     "x86-64" 
                       login                         user               effective_user 
                   "davidri"                    "davidri"                    "davidri"
```

Many thanks

Comment: Do you have `RTools` installed? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50278862/786542

Comment: I think so, when I run `> pkgbuild::find_rtools()` I get `[1] TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

devtools isn't installed as its dependency rcmdcheck did not install

Try re-installing that

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it seems I cannot properly install crmdcheck either...

```
> install.packages("rcmdcheck")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/davidri/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
          binary source needs_compilation
rcmdcheck  1.3.1  1.3.2             FALSE

installing the source package ‘rcmdcheck’

trying URL 'http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/src/contrib/rcmdcheck_1.3.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1408582 bytes (1.3 MB)
downloaded 1.3 MB

In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rcmdcheck’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\davidri\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpE9Zll0\downloaded_packages’
```