# Error R version installed with different internals, have installed ggplot many times

Tags: r, ggplot2

Whenever I try to load `ggplot` the following error comes:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’:
>    package ‘scales’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version

Comment: Can you add the results of `sessionInfo()` to your question please

Comment: Have you reinstalled `scales`? What are the versions of `R`, `ggplot2` and `scales`? As suggested please add `sessionInfo()`

Comment: > sessionsinfo()
Error in sessionsinfo() : could not find function "sessionsinfo"
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
> sessioninfo()
Error in sessioninfo() : could not find function "sessioninfo"

Comment: I am new to R, so what are scales. my R version is 3.5.2 and studio version is 1.1.463, ggplot2 version is 3.1.0...How to check scales and what is it?

Comment: @TaimurKhan ; R is case sensitive and functions need to be spelled correctly -- you need to use `sessionInfo()`

Comment: R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7600)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.2 tools_3.5.2    gtable_0.2.0   yaml_2.2.0     grid_3.5.2

Comment: @TaimurKhan: Restart R or RStudio, then run this line `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE, ask = FALSE, repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com")`

Comment: After that, run `install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)`

Comment: upon entering the first command:update.packages this error comes: Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'

Comment: Remove the `repos = ...` part then try again

Comment: You might need RTools. If so, follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50278862/786542)

Comment: @TaimurKhan: Relevant https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115005709447-Can-t-install-package- & https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205198138-packages-installation-problem